# IIS 7 Application Pool Private Memory Usage

Tags: asp.net, memory, application-pool

For IIS 7,
Help for Recycling Conditions for Application Pool says that **Private Memory Usage** is ...privately allocated system **physical** memory ...
(The property is named `Maximum Used Memory` in IIS 6.)

And, Event Log entry when application pool recycles;
"A worker process with process id of '4824' serving application pool '(thepool)' has requested a recycle because it reached its **private bytes memory limit**."

Thus, if its **private bytes** then it must be the **committed** memory which **physical memory + page file**. But, help says its **physical** memory(in that case property must be named **private working set.**)

> **ASP.NET Performance Monitoring, and When to Alert Administrators**
>
> **Private Bytes.** The current size, in bytes, of the **committed memory** owned by this process.
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx#monitor_perf_topic12

i don't find any correction to this documentation, or am i missing something?