# Metrics for IIS Application Pool Recycling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, perfmon

We have been investigating an ASP.NET MVC web site that is experiencing relatively high memory usage. To investigate we used Windows PerfMon and the following metrics:

- Private Bytes
- Working Set
- Working Set (Private)

Which of these metrics (or what other metric) does IIS monitor for the "Private Memory Limit (KB)" limit setting? I am unable to find a definitive answer as to the specific metric - although I suspect it may be 'Private Bytes'.

Comment: I would say `Private Bytes` but I can't find any definitive answer. This question has already been asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324575/iis-7-application-pool-private-memory-usage (no answer). But why would you need this information ? All you want is to find the memory leak ? Try to use DebugDiag to analyze your application.

Comment: We don't have a memory leak as such but are experiencing high memory usage related to Telerik server side reporting components in particular. The site is on a shared host and it will get recycled if memory usage is above a particular limit.